# Second comments section for one post/page

Tags: posts, pages, comments

For a project, I need to have 2 comments sections related to the same post/page. Is there a way or a plugin to do that ? By default, Wordpress allow only one comment section for one post/page.

Thanks a lot,
Cédric

Answer (score 0):

When you add/display comments you could use a different comment_type

```
$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => 1,
    'comment_content' => 'content here',
    'comment_type' => 'comment_type_a',
);

wp_insert_comment($data);
```

This means you can query comments by comment_type depending on where you want to show them.